# Laravel Route Model Binding - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, route-model-binding

I'm trying to use Laravel's route model binding.  I've setup a binding in the RoutesServiceProvider to perform some custom resolution logic. This works fine for the `attributable` parameter which requires both a string name and an id to resolve.

However, when I attempt to type cast a method to take advantage of implicit binding for another model it fails with the error

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::{closure}() must be an instance of App\Models\Staff, string given, called in /var/www/html/ngj_form/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php on line 198

After some debugging I can see that it's passing the `{attrId}` part of the route as the second typecast parameter in the method definition below. ID is a string therefore it fails. But why is it even trying to pass this parameter?

The Route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/admin/create-staff-payment/{attributable}/{attrId}/staff-member/{staff}/', 'Admin\StaffBalances@granularStaffBalance');
```

The typecast controller method looks like this:

```
 public function granularStaffBalance(Attributable $attributable, Staff $staff)
{
    dd('huh?');
}
```

And the RouteServiceProvider looks like this:

```
  public function boot()
{

    // Bind Attributable (wedding|trial)
    Route::bind('attributable', function ($attributable, $route) {

        $attributableId = $route->parameter('attrId');

        switch($attributable){
            case 'wedding':
                $attributable = Wedding::class;
                break;
            case 'trial':
                $attributable = Trial::class;
                break;
            default:
                throw new \Exception('Type parameter provided is not supported.'); //TODO change this to 404 redirect
        }

        return $attributable::where('id', $attributableId)->firstOrFail();
    });

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after further research (no thanks to the Laravel docs) I think this is expected behaviour. If you pass three parameters in a route your controller method will expect to receive them in the order they appear in the url.  I guess I'd assumed from the docs that the selection of parameters was more intelligent than this but I guessed wrong.

The way I've gotten around it is via an answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619512/laravel-5-4-how-to-do-not-use-route-parameter-in-controller).

Apparently you can forget parameters as a means of discarding them and this lets my controller method accept two parameters instead of three.

So now my `RouteServiceProvider` looks like this (posting here in case it helps someone else):

```
 public function boot()
    {

        parent::boot();

        // Bind Attributable (wedding|trial)
        Route::bind('attributable', function ($attributable, $route) {

            $attributableId = $route->parameter('attrId');

            switch($attributable){
                case 'wedding':
                    $attributable = Wedding::class;
                    break;
                case 'trial':
                    $attributable = Trial::class;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new \Exception('Type parameter provided is not supported.'); //TODO change this to 404 redirect
            }

            // We don't want to use this parameter in any controller methods so we can drop it here.
            // This fixes an issue where it was being passed into methods that needs $attributable, $staff
            $route->forgetParameter('attrId');

            return $attributable::where('id', $attributableId)->firstOrFail();
        });
...
```